# Best way to show results with a list of options

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a "Oregon Trail" like game with JAVA for my Computer Science class. It's all going well so far, but I would like some suggestions on ways of doing the following:

[image]

The words at the bottom "Health", "Stats", etc are buttons. I was wondering what the best way of making those buttons present information would be. Is there a way I could show them in that information in one of the bottom squares, and when a different button is clicked change the info to that one? Or would it be best to have popup frames to display the information?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I am too new to post Images.

Comment: I can't explain things very well. Basically I want to click a button and have it present information to the user. If I added that information to one of the squares in the layout and clicked a different button to display different information, how would I replace the first information for the new information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, I'd go with display the content or info of the button in the panels above.

It keeps the information together in a single place and generally makes it easier to manage, no disappearing windows behind other windows for example.

You have any number of options depending on the information you want to display.  You could simply use a none editable `JTextArea` if the information is just text, or a `JList` if you want to list items if the data is more structured, a `JTable` and even a `JTree` if you want to group the data into some kind of groupable hierarchy.

You could use combinations of each, based on your needs

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards as well, now I need to play around with those a bit and figure out ways of doing this.